# Ajv - how to mark inner schema as optional?

Tags: typescript, ajv

Given the following ajv ( v8.11.2 ) sample schema

```
import Ajv, { JSONSchemaType } from "ajv";

interface MyType {
    myProp?: OtherType;
}

interface OtherType {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}

const otherSchema: JSONSchemaType<OtherType> = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        foo: { type: 'string', minLength: 1 },
        bar: { type: 'number' },
    },
    required: ['foo', 'bar'],
    additionalProperties: false
};

const mySchema: JSONSchemaType<MyType> = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        myProp: otherSchema,
    },
    required: [],
    additionalProperties: false,
};
```

I get the following error

> Types of property '$ref' are incompatible. Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I think this is because TS doesn't know that `myProp` of `mySchema` might be undefined, although it does not exist in the required array.

Do you have any ideas how to fix the schema?

Comment: I'd assume that's because you declare in your `MyType` a type for your `myProp` to be `OtherType`, but then when you declare your schema, you set an object of type `JSONSchemaType<MyType>` to that property and TypeScript is telling you about type mismatch, because `OtherType` is not `JSONSchemaType<OtherType>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```js
import { JSONSchemaType } from "ajv";

interface OtherType {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

interface MyType {
  myProp?: OtherType;
}

export const otherSchema: JSONSchemaType<OtherType> = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    foo: { type: "string", minLength: 1 },
    bar: { type: "number" }
  },
  required: ["foo", "bar"],
  additionalProperties: false
};

export const mySchema: JSONSchemaType<MyType> = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    // nest your objects inside "properties"
    myProp: {
      ...otherSchema,
      nullable: true // this nullable param is important!
    }
  },
  required: [],
  additionalProperties: false
};
```

Here is a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/ajv-schema-json-nested-qu9e7q?file=/src/schemas.ts

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment, I'd assume that's because you declare in your `MyType` a type for your `myProp` to be `OtherType`, but then when you declare your schema, you set an object of type `JSONSchemaType<MyType>` to that property and TypeScript is telling you about type mismatch, because `OtherType` is not `JSONSchemaType<OtherType>`

Try to adjust your `MyType` to be:

```
interface MyType {
  myProp?: JSONSchemaType<OtherType>;
}
```

Though I have never used `ajv` package and have no idea about `JSONSchemaType` type and what is required for it to be fulfilled. But my answer should cover the error that you posted

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply :) Unfortunately, this is not the way ajv "would do it". This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/74844829/19698303